# How do archive containers work?

Tags: c++, algorithm

For learning purposes, I want to make a simple archive format where I can put in files and extract them. No compression. What resources, or techniques would be recommended for creating something like this?

The result wold be something like files.bin

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put a header at the beginning of the archive with offsets to where each file lies inside archive. Or just store them sequentially, putting the size before each file.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest format for this in common use is [tar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_%28file_format%29). It's ridiculously simple: A fixed length (512 byte) header provides information about the next file in the archive, including its name, length, permission bits, etc, followed by the file itself. Since the length is included in the header, you can skip over the file to the next header, and so forth. It also means that a concatenation of several tar files is itself a valid tar file.